# Database deadlock detected

Tags: 8, caching

On Drupal 8 we're getting a few deadlock conditions - most connected with the cache. There are quite a few answers to this issue but not so much for D8 (which has very different caching mechanism). Is there any way to resolve/mitigate?

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[40P01]: Deadlock detected: 7 ERROR: deadlock detected DETAIL: 
Process 9131 waits for ShareRowExclusiveLock on relation 8341492 of database 8341380; blocked by process 9130. 
Process 9130 waits for ShareRowExclusiveLock on relation 8341562 of database 8341380; blocked by process 9131. 
HINT: See server log for query details.: LOCK TABLE {cache_bootstrap} IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE; 
Array ( ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() 
    (line 847 of /var/xxx/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
```

Comment: No, this is not caching related, this deadlock occurs while saving a content entity. Such a deadlock is very unlikely unless you have an unusual amount of content entity saves. Do you have a lot of POST requests saving data? Or do you have a use case where you update content entities in GET requests?

Comment: Checking dependencies of cache_bootstrap I could find only one core service connecting this to content entities, PermissionsHashGenerator. So I would start looking for unusual saves of users.

Comment: Thanks @4k4  - how can you tell its content?
I'm not quite sure what is causing it so would like to add some debug code to provide a bit more information. Any thoughts on best place for that?

Comment: You can tell by the error message. The deadlock happens in `SqlContentEntityStorage->save()`, which starts a database transaction and then causes a deadlock in `cache_bootstrap`.

Comment: Thanks - anyone got a good way of reproducing (on dev)!

Answer (score 1):

You can try and add the following lines to your settings.php file :

```
$databases['default']['default']['init_commands'] = array(
  'isolation' => "SET SESSION tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED'"
);
```

https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005253954-Fixing-database-deadlocks

Comment: This seems tailored to Acquia hosting and for MySQL (thought there are similar for Postgres etc)

Comment: Has this worked, @jons?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable alternative cache implementation (with cache bootstrap) [memcache](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) or [redis](https://www.drupal.org/project/redis). Read more about deadlocks: https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005253954-Fixing-database-deadlocks

Comment: thanks - I've looked at redis. I guess that just reduces the possibility of locks - rather than resolving the underlying DB/code logic issues?

Answer (score 0):

i had this bug a while ago , and i found this [fixing dead locks in drupal](https://groups.drupal.org/node/415883)

```
ALTER TABLE semaphore ENGINE = MEMORY;
ALTER TABLE semaphore DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD PRIMARY KEY (name, value) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD UNIQUE name (name) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE semaphore DROP INDEX value;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD INDEX value (value) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE semaphore DROP INDEX expire;
ALTER TABLE semaphore ADD INDEX expire (expire) USING BTREE;
```

I hope this helps , it worked for me .

Comment: is semaphore fix related just to D7?

Comment: i tried it on d8 too it seems to work